# Printing out a table using TextView and SetText

Tags: android, textview, settext

I'm trying to print out a table using TextView and setText, but I can't get the table to print out correctly. It only prints out a single line. As I understand it setText overwrites the previous line? How can I get around this problem so that my for loop prints out every line instead of just overwriting the current line?

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Character \t Correct \t Incorrect \t Percentage\n");
    ll.addView(tv);

    for(int counter = 0; counter<scores1.length;counter++){
        tv.setText(level1[counter] + "\t " + correct1[counter] + "\t " + incorrect1[counter] + "\t " + percentage1[counter] + "\n");
    }

    this.setContentView(sv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a `ListView`, see

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

There's an example on the Android `ListView` page and you can also check out:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample

`ListView` takes care of creating the `TextView`s for you and re-uses them to save memory and offers adapters to use data from the database and other sources.

A quick hack for your code would be:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter<scores1.length;counter++){
    tv = new TextView(this);
    ll.addView(tv);
    tv.setText(level1[counter] + "\t " + correct1[counter] + "\t " + incorrect1[counter] + "\t " + percentage1[counter] + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each column you need to instantiate a new TextView, and `setText()` under that instance.

Also, maybe it's better to use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) inside your LinearLayout.